# Updating a many to many association in Datamapper with PostgreSQL database

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, datamapper

I have a fairly run of the mill many-to-many relationship between two models: User and Interest.

When I migrate my database a interest_users table gets created, with two columns: user_id and interest_id.

Creating a user record is fine and the rows in the link table get created fine. However when I go to update a record I get the following:

```
ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "interest_users_pkey"
DETAIL:  Key (user_id, interest_id)=(1, 2) already exists.
```

This means the new user-interests links are not created. What's more I can't seem to delete links either.

I'm using datamapper on rails 3 with a postgresql database. Has anyone else had the same problem?

Comment: The error message for the update states the problem clearly, doesn't it? You are trying to change a link so that it would be the same as an already existing one. But those links are defined unique, so you cannot do that. Any error messages when you try to delete links?

Comment: I understand that but I would have assumed datamapper would only try to create the link if it didn't already exist. No error message when I try to delete either. Perhaps I need a separate unique key id on the link table? but im unsure how to do this in datamapper without using a link model and I'd like to avoid those if possible...

Answer (score 1):

You should be sure if it is an UPDATE and if it is trying to change (set) the fields user_id, interest_id. Many times this is because the WHERE clause isn't considering the primary key fields. The other possibility is that key (user_id, interest_id)=(1, 2) that already exists is an orphan data, if so you should make sure that you have some `:constraint => :destroy` enabled in relationships.